# Git and R - opening existing project und adding new scripts

Tags: r, git, commit

So I am new to Git. I have linked my R project (**edit**: in R studio) with Git a while ago and everything woked fine. I have created some scripts, committed them and everything shows up nicely in my private Git Repository.

However, when I open the project now, there are no scripts. **How can I continue working on the script that I have committed the last time?** I have opened the file through `file` -> `open file` but upon saving it did not shot in the Git Pane.

I also opened a new script, added some code and saved it. After saving I was expecting the new file to show up in my Git Pane (with tho question marks next to it). It did not show up. **How can I add new script to my existing project and commit them to the existing repository?**

Comment: Which application are you using ? Is it something like R Studio (which is different from base R) or Eclipse ?

Comment: @PaulHurleyuk i am using R Studio

Comment: You don't see the files in the file directory in RStudio?  So you see them in your regular file manager on your computer?

Comment: When I open the project it does not open any scripts. I see the scripts in my regular file manager and can open them in R studio also, but when i do any changes and save them, they do not appear in the Git Pane and i therefore i not commit them.

Comment: Could it be that you have the scripts in a `.gitignore` directory?

Comment: ok, i figured it out - beginners mistake: i did not save the scripts in the correct folder.